# Extract data using salesforce api

Tags: api, data, data-export

I need to get all data of a specific table using salesforce in one go. Is there any API to do so?

Comment: You could always use the free DataLoader which accesses the API or look at the API documentation at https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Salesforce_APIs

Comment: Without a context its difficult to comment

Comment: What is the frequency to get all data from salesforce. Is it a once in a while  or it is daily, weekly , monthly. ?

Answer (score 2):

If you need details of the different Salesforce APIs the starting point for the documentation is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Salesforce_APIs). Salesforce supports REST and SOAP API with a number of specialised API for the Metadata used in deployment, Chatter and for the APEX development language. Please start there to find out the different API and ask specific question here as they arise.

To just extract data from an object the free Salesforce Data Loader tool is able to do this and is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/data_loader.htm). Data Loader uses the API to extract data and can be used for both standard and custom object's data.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible with REST API

https://[YOURDOMAIN].rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/[EXTERNALKEY-DATAEXTENSION]/rowset

With this URI above you can to retrieve until 2500 records, but in the response exist a link to the nexts 2500 records.

So you can to paginate this datas
/v1/customobjectdata/token/e05b8be5-94ea-4147-af3e-4ec2b40a7d12/rowset?$page=1

Response Example :

```
{
"links": {

"self": "/v1/customobjectdata/token/e05b8be5-94ea-4147-af3e-4ec2b40a7d12/rowset?$page=1",

"next": "/v1/customobjectdata/token/e05b8be5-94ea-4147-af3e-4ec2b40a7d12/rowset?$page=2"


    },
    "requestToken": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "tokenExpireDateUtc": "2019-06-10T20:11:56.523",
    "customObjectId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "customObjectKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "pageSize": 2500,
    "page": 1,
    "count": 2506,
    "items": [
        {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SOAP API, there are two ways to get data from a data extension.

1. Retrieve Requests, can retrieve up to 2500 records per request. This is recommended for data extensions less than 50,000 records.
   See: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm
2. Extract Requests, which will export the entire DE to a file in the related FTP account. See the following for examples:
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_data_extract_activity_with_the_soap_web_service_api.htm

If using an Extract Request, ensure that the extract ID = bb94a04d-9632-4623-be47-daabc3f588a6, use the DECustomerKey parameter to specify the DE and include all other required parameters.

Answer (score 0):

we built a tool for exactly this! You can export your Accounts, leads, contacts and more tables from your Salesforce account. Simply connect Cloudslurp, select the table and then you are given a URL with a direct link to the data in JSON format. You can load it into Excel or analytics tools or save it for backup/import purposes. Cloudslurp handles all the authorization and pagination for you.

https://www.cloudslurp.com/#/?connectorname=salesforce